# AWS for Hybrid Mobile Applications (Cordova)

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services

Does Amazon Web Service provide support for building Hybrid Mobile Apps?
Is it possible to use their services along with the app?

Answer (score 2):

As AWS provides PAAS / SAAS as a backendservice and an app can be build as a client that consumes these services: YES!

You want to set up a node.js / express server with some kind of DB access? -> Set it up on AWS ([Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)) , if you like. You need cloud storage? Get some from Amazon..

Ofcourse, this is not specific to AWS, there are (a lot of) other service providers out there in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

"Does Amazon Web Service provide support for building Hybrid Mobile Apps?"

You can get yourself an EC2 instance, install everything you need to build on there and run Jenkins on it.  This isn't going to help with iOS builds that need to run on Mac OS X (for which services like PhoneGap Build or Mac in the cloud leasing companies such as MacStadium are available).  If you're building Android / Blackberry then AWS would work for this.

"Is it possible to use their services along with the app?"

Absolutely.  Most can be accessed via standard APIs from any mobile platform, hybrid or fully native application.  For example you might use S3 for uploading images from devices to the cloud, EC2, Elastic Beanstalk or Lambda to do server side processing / API work, and RDS as a data store.